# How to enable console print of traceback in PyQtGraph

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyqtgraph

Is there a preferred way in pyqtgraph to configure it to dump errors to the terminal?

In working with sample script https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/examples/FlowchartCustomNode.py I tweaked it in a way that left a flaw in `UnsharpMaskNode.process`. There was no traceback so I tracked the error handling back to line 315 in https://github.com/pyqtgraph/pyqtgraph/blob/develop/pyqtgraph/flowchart/Node.py in `UnsharpMaskNode` parent class' `Node.update` method in  where the error is swallowed by bare try/except. I uncommented a pyqtgraph developer's call to `printExc` in that except block which yes, prints, but I'd hoped to find find a constructor flag, a set method, a DEBUG const, anything to conditionally indicate that the traceback should tee to stderr.

For example, add a RuntimeError in method `UnsharpMaskNode.process` as shown below  and execute the script. The exception will not be seen but in the GUI the corresponding ImageViewNode will present no image, implicitly indicating failure.

```
def process(self, dataIn, display=True):
    # CtrlNode has created self.ctrls, which is a dict containing {ctrlName: widget}
    sigma = self.ctrls['sigma'].value()
    strength = self.ctrls['strength'].value()
    raise RuntimeError('This will silently fail')
    output = dataIn - (strength * pg.gaussianFilter(dataIn, (sigma,sigma)))
    return {'dataOut': output}
```

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: Expanded question as per suggestion of @tmoreau